# Which charset to use for multipart/alternative text/plain?

Tags: mime, email-client

My task is to send emails which most recipients will read as HTML. A MIME text/plain alternative will be included for those who cannot read the HTML or choose not to.

The HTML is in English and has characters from Latin-1 Supplement and General Punctuation, so US-ASCII or ISO-8859-1 would not retain all of them. I could mitigate by substituting characters before encoding.

My question is which charset to use for the text/plain part? US-ASCII, ISO-8859-1 or UTF-8. Related questions are what text based email clients are still being used, and do they support these charsets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had no answers about how well text based email clients read charsets, so I had a look at how common email senders encode their alternative text.

Both GMail and Outlook (2007) choose the smallest charset that can represent the content. In other words they use US-ASCII if the text is simple, ISO-8859-* if European characters are present or UTF-8 for a large span of characters.

Outlook was a bit buggy on one of my tests. I put in some General Punctuation. Outlook encoded it using WINDOWS-1252 but tagged it as ISO-8859-1.

The answer to the question in pseudo code is

```
for charset in us-ascii, iso-8859-1, utf-8
    if encode(text, charset)
        break
```

The list of charsets is appropriate for the input I am expecting.